# CHECKSUM_AGG for several tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, checksum

I'm using Microsoft Sql Server. I get CHECKSUM for my table [Test1]:

```
Select CHECKSUM_AGG(binary_checksum(*)) from [MyDB].[dbo].[Test1]
```

I get: 1878191716

Tell me please, **How can I get one CHECKSUM for several tables at once?** (For example, for [Test1], [Test2] and [Test3])

p.s. Tables are different. Number of tables is more than 10. I need one CHECKSUM.
I watch whether there was a change in at least one of the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *first* get the `BINARY_CHECKSUM` values for all rows in the relevant tables, and *then* take the `CHECKSUM_AGG`, thus:

```
;WITH EveryRow(Val) AS (
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) FROM Table2
UNION ALL
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) FROM Table3
-- etc
)
SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(Val)
FROM EveryRow
;
```

You would need to dynamically build a SQL statement and execute it, if you wanted to *compute* rather than *list* the tables to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they have the same columns, you can use `union all`:

```
Select CHECKSUM_AGG(binary_checksum(*))
from ((select t.* from [MyDB].[dbo].[Test1] t) union all
      (select t.* from [MyDB].[dbo].[Test2] t) union all
      (select t.* from [MyDB].[dbo].[Test3] t) 
     ) t;
```

If they don't have the same columns, I would suggest that you calculate three separate values.

Comment: Tables are different. Number of tables is more than 10. I need one CHECKSUM.